# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN COUNT() GROUPBY converted to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working in .NET Core 2.0 MVC with Entity Framework and I am trying to convert a SQL statement into an EF query. Here is the original SQL:

```
SELECT
t.LastName, FirstName, t.teacherId
,courseCode
,classSection
,roomId
,number
,DayID
,periodId
FROM Classes cl
INNER JOIN Courses cr on cr.courseId = cl.courseId
INNER JOIN vwClassSchedule cs on cs.ClassId = cl.classId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Teachers t on t.TeacherID = cl.teacherId
LEFT OUTER JOIN(select classid, count(classid) as number
from CourseEnrollment group by classId) ce on cl.classId = ce.classId
order by LastName, dayId, periodId
```

The last LEFT OUTER JOIN is my problem. I have not found a solution that performs well. Here is the EF statement I have come up with thus far:

```
var Courses = _Context.Classes
                                .Include(t => t.Teachers)
                                .Include(c => c.Courses)
                                .Include(s => s.ClassSchedule)
                                .OrderBy(t => t.Teachers.LastName)
                                .ThenBy(s => s.ClassSchedule.DayID)
                                .ThenBy(s => s.ClassSchedule.PeriodID)
                                .Select(p => new ClassDTO
                                {
                                    TeacherId = p.teacherId,
                                    FirstName = p.Teachers.FirstName,
                                    LastName = p.Teachers.LastName,
                                    Course = p.Courses.courseCode,
                                    Section = p.classSection,
                                    Room = p.roomId,
                                    Students = 0,
                                    Day = p.ClassSchedule.DayID,
                                    Block = p.ClassSchedule.PeriodID,
                                    ClassId = p.classId
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

The only workable solution I have come up with is to loop through the Courses result and calculate the Student count for each result and that is a huge perfomance killer. The original SQL runs in under a second whereas my second loop takes almost 30 seconds. There has to be a better way.

Comment: The `CourseEnrollment` from your SQL query seems to relate to `Class` only, so I'm not sure what `Courses` loop are you talking about. If the SQL query is correct, then your `Class` entity should have `ICollection<CourseEnrollment> CourseEnrollments` collection navigation property, so inside the LINQ query you would use `Students = p.CourseEnrollments.Count()`. Btw, consider using singular names for entity types and reference navigation properties - the way it is now it's hard to read and follow the multiplicity. Also `Include`s are not needed when projecting to DTO.

Comment: i can help with linq

Comment: **Update:** Once I had a test server set up and published the website to it, performance was a non-issue. Adding this to the 'refactor one day' pile.